# Accessing # character in URL through $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, url

I am passing data through the URL and then accessing it using PHP's $_GET[] function. If the URL has a '#' somewhere in it, then the GET request seem to truncate the string. For example,

> http://example.com/yyy.php?version=0.88&value=ART:C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced
>   D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform
>   Common Language Infrastructure License
>   CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions
>   .cs Website C Sharp Programming at
>   Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ˈsiː ˈʃɑrp/
>   see sharp) is a multi-paradigm
>   programming language encompassing
>   imperative, declarative, functional,
>   generic, object-oriented
>   (class-based), and component-oriented
>   programming disciplines.@10902

`$_GET['value']` returns:

> ART:C_Sharp_(programming_language)@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced D, F

Is there a way to avoid this? Should I strip all #'s out of the values posted to the URL?

The URL location is accessed from the client side javascript code using XMLHttpRequest(). The encoded string from javascript functionality encodeURIComponent() is,

> ART%3AC_Sharp_%2528programming_language%2529%40Multi-paradigm_programming_language%40Influenced%20D%2C%20F%23%2C%20Java%205%2C%20Nemerle%2C%20Vala%20Platform%20Common%20Language%20Infrastructure%20License%20CLR%20Proprietary%20Usual%20file%20extensions%20.cs%20Website%20C%20Sharp%20Programming%20at%20Wikibooks%20C%23%20(pronounced%20%2F%CB%88si%CB%90%20%CB%88%CA%83%C9%91rp%2F%20see%20sharp)%20is%20a%20multi-paradigm%20programming%20language%20encompassing%20imperative%2C%20declarative%2C%20functional%2C%20generic%2C%20object-oriented%20(class-based)%2C%20and%20component-oriented%20programming%20disciplines.%8681

decoded output logged by 'yyy.php':

> ART:C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced
>   D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform
>   Common Language Infrastructure License
>   CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions
>   .cs Website C Sharp Programming at
>   Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ËˆsiË
>   ËˆÊƒÉ‘rp/ see sharp) is a
>   multi-paradigm programming language
>   encompassing imperative, declarative,
>   functional, generic, object-oriented
>   (class-based), and component-oriented
>   programming disciplines.@8681

Logged output without using encodeURIComponent() and what should be the expected result:

> ART:C_Sharp_(programming_language)@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced
>   D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform
>   Common Language Infrastructure License
>   CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions
>   .cs Website C Sharp Programming at
>   Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ˈsiː ˈʃɑrp/
>   see sharp) is a multi-paradigm
>   programming language encompassing
>   imperative, declarative, functional,
>   generic, object-oriented
>   (class-based), and component-oriented
>   programming disciplines.@8681

Comment: can you put url up there, there `_%` in your url??

Comment: @experimentX: ok I edited.....now how do I fully recover the encoded/morphed characters?

Comment: all right, I think the best way seems to be to replace # with %23. I do not know what other characters like # might create troubles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

A `#` in a URL string is a fragment identifier. You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the string before adding it to the URL.

You cannot do anything about it in your `yyy.php` script as PHP does not have access to URL fragments.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: aah sorry i forgot to mention.....these values are sent from the client side javascript using XMLHttpRequest(). Any similar function in javascript to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try passing parameters encoding [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
header('Location: http://your_url?version=0.88&value='.urlencode('ART:C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform Common Language Infrastructure License CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions .cs Website C Sharp Programming at Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ˈsiː ˈʃɑrp/ see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming language encompassing imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines.@10902'));
```

On js you have

```
window.location = 'index.php?value='+encodeURIComponent('ART:C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform Common Language Infrastructure License CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions .cs Website C Sharp Programming at Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ˈsiː ˈʃɑrp/ see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming language encompassing imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines.@10902');
```

**UPDATE**

```
window.location = 'index.php?version=0.88&value='+encodeURIComponent('ART:C_Sharp_(programming_language)@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform Common Language Infrastructure License CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions .cs Website C Sharp Programming at Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ˈsiː ˈʃɑrp/ see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming language encompassing imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines.@8681');
```

[image]

Comment: Just being picky here but a location header value should be a complete URI, including scheme (http, https, etc), host and path

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention.....these values are sent from the client side javascript using XMLHttpRequest(). Any similar function in javascript to handle this issue?

Comment: @experimentX: The web site http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp says "This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ #". Am I missing something?

Comment: @user548245 use encodeURIComponent and please some take display name.

Comment: @experimentX: thanks for that. For decoding then on 'yyy.php' should I use 'urldecode()' and will it work fine on javascript encoded string? I am sorry I am new to this. Will really appreciate your reply.

Comment: @aryan no, php automatically does that.

Comment: @experimentX: ok this is the decoded string:  **ART:C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29@Multi-paradigm_programming_language@Influenced D, F#, Java 5, Nemerle, Vala Platform Common Language Infrastructure License CLR Proprietary Usual file extensions .cs Website C Sharp Programming at Wikibooks C# (pronounced /ËˆsiË ËˆÊƒÉ‘rp/ see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming language encompassing imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines.@8681**

Comment: The log entry before using encodeURIComponent was: ART:C_Sharp_(programming_language)..........  which now is ART:C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29......just wondering how to get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape that character, as it's normally used by the browser as a `hashtag` to scroll to certain elements.

In PHP, you use the `urlencode()` function on the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

The portion of the URL after the `#` is the fragment and is never sent to the server. It is handled by the user agent only. You'll need to use JavaScript to interact with it.

Though, in your example, you'll need to escape it so its meaning is taken literally. As others have pointed out, `urlencode()` is perfect for that.

Answer (score 0):

did u try **parse_url** with **[PHP_URL_FRAGMENT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** ?

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```